# Algorithm for waypoint path following?

Tags: path-finding

I have a worldmap, with different cities on it. The player can choose a city from a menu, or click on an available cities on the world map, and the toon should walk over there.

I want him to follow a predefined path.

[image: cities]

Lets say our hero is on the city 1. He clicks on city 4. I want him to follow the path to city 2 and from there to city 4.

I was handling this easily with arrow movement (left right top bottom) since its a single check.

Now I'm not sure how I should do this. Should I loop threw each possible path and check which one leads me to D the fastest ... and if I do how do I avoid running in circle forever with cities 1-5-2  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're dealing with a very large grid, A* is overkill.  You're probably better off with Dijkstra's Shortest Path, which has the advantage of being far easier to implement, to boot.

A* matters when you have an enormous number of possible paths, like when searching a large game grid.  However it also relies on datastructures, particularly the priority queue, which aren't commonly available (and when are are often inefficient.)

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: True that, I used (3D)-A* a lot in the past few weeks, and somehow blocked out everything else... In retrospect I would choose this for your (smallscale?) Problem.

Comment: alright i'll check for it, thanks for the info ! I didnt knew it was possible to tweak those pathfinding to follow a define path, I always use them with grid pathfinding.

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier What is a grid other than a graph with a fancy layout? It is easy to see each gridcell (Node) individually, but to search a grid, the connections (Edges) are far more interesting.

Comment: @Larethian Your getting into very theoric place, and thats not my forte ... I got no idea how the computer place/see/computes these "edges" between each cell. If I knew, I couldve probably find my way around this easily.

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier I believe you misunderstood me. Take a chessboard. You have gridcells and borders of these gridcells. Now, instead of drawing squares for each gridcell, draw a dot. And at every border, draw a line to the dot that is on the other side of the border. If you are done, you have 8x8 Dots all connected with their neighbors. Now forget the chessboard, and name your dots Town1, Town2 ect. You've got a graph connecting towns to each other. You can find from Town1 to Town42 in this graph the same way as if you had named the fields on the chessboard, and searched there. Grid=Graph#

Comment: I'm a "regular" programmer, dabbling into game programming for fun ... reading about dijkstra more in details on wiki and I just realize what makes in more complicated for me to understand everything are the definitions and the fact poeple always assume you know what they are talking about when they shorcuts on details ... what I really lack is an "advance math for programmer" class to really understand all these mathematics definitions/concept without having to dig them out.

Comment: ok for a grid, but I didnt see how I could apply this to a non-grid earlier ... I dont want town1 to be linked to town2 and town 9 and town 10(all bordering cells). I want it linked only to town10. but I think I see what you mean, I didnt read previously about dijkstra and it seems it'll allow me to do just that.

Comment: anyway, break time is over, back to work for me. I'll take time to read this threw tonight and try to implement it. thanks for the info

Comment: @Larethian Graphs that don't constitute grids include the map in the board game Risk, the street map that Google Maps finds routes on, the structure created by theoretical positioning availabilities when using a graph to model slot placements eg in timeslot fitting, states in a state machine, waypoints in a master grid for unit pathfinding, the map of configurations made availabe in a trading situation where each trade changes each partner's expected responses, etc.  (Graphs are _everywhere_.)

Comment: @JohnHaugeland The point I was trying to make was not that only grids are graphs, but that everything that applies to grids also applies to graphs (as they can be viewed as the same). After understanding that A* ect. apply to graphs, Thierry should be able to apply every Grid-Algorithm on Graphs as well (or so the idea). 

Thierry: If you have questions to a specific problem, feel free to ask a new question, if it is something minor come back here. 

Apropos here, we should probably move to a chat?

Comment: @Larethian Thank you for explaining my own answer to me in comments on my answer :|

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier why would it make a difference whether your graph was a grid?  It's an expansion of the next step of paths compared by their cost.

Comment: Continuation in [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16596/algorithm-for-waypoint-path-following).

Answer (score 1):

Any A* implementation will do the trick. Look on Wikipedia for example.

A* even allows you to add weight to your connections, resulting in not the route with the fewest hops, but the route with the shortest travel time beeing selected.

Example: `Frankfurt→NYC`
There is a connection `Frankfurt→Moskau→NYC`. This one has 2 hops, but the cost is high.
Then there os a way `Frankfurt→Rotterdam→London→NYC`. This one has three hops, but the cost is low.

Adding costs is worthwile if distance, the mean of transport or something else is important.

Comment: and here I though a* was for "regular" pathfinding ... I used it for my battle AI ... didnt knew i could implement it to do way point pathfinding too